# If $G$ is Euler's graph with odd number of vertices, prove that $G^c$ is also Euler's graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an Euler's graph with odd number of vertices and graph $G^c$ is a connected graph. Prove that  $G^c$ is an Euler's graph.

The solution:

Number of odd vertices of $G$ is $2r+1,r>0$. Since $G$ is an Euler's graph, all of it's vertices degrees are even number, so $d_G(v)=2k$. I understand the previous statements, now $d_{G^c}(v)=2r+1-2k-1=2r-2k$, from which we conclude that every vertex of graph $G^c$ has even degree, and since it is connected, it is an Euler's graph.

I don't understand this part $d_{G^c}(v)=2r+1-2k-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of a vertex $v$ in $G$, there are $2r$ other vertices. Therefore, taking the complementary graph $G^c$ means erasing the $d_G(v)=2k$ edges connecting $v$ to $2k$ vertices, and adding an edge between $v$ and the $2r-2k$ other vertices, giving $d_{G^c}(v)=2r-2k$.

I believe the expression $2r+1-2k-1$ comes from a more general formula $$d_{G^c}(v)=|G|-1-d_G(v).$$ Once again, you can see that the number that matters is the $|G|-1$ vertices other than $v$.